# Laravel Livewire: Bootstrap Select-Picker unable to render

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-9, bootstrap-selectpicker

I want to load categories and multiple sub categories according to all the categories that are selected, inside a multi-step form at step 4, but I am not able to select multiple categories using [bootstrap selectpicker (multiple selects)](https://developer.snapappointments.com/bootstrap-select/examples/#multiple-select-boxes) library inside livewire component. The issue with using Bootstrap-Select with Livewire is that both of these libraries use JavaScript to update the page dynamically, which is probably causing conflicts. If I try accessing the same without livewire, it works perfectly fine, but with livewire I am unable to render it.

**form.blade**

```
@section('content')
    <livewire:multi-step-form />
@endsection

@push('before-styles')
    <link rel="stylesheet prefetch" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.1/css/bootstrap-select.css" />
@endpush
@push('before-scripts')
    <script rel="javascript prefetch" src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script rel="javascript prefetch" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-select/1.13.18/js/bootstrap-select.min.js" integrity="sha512-yDlE7vpGDP7o2eftkCiPZ+yuUyEcaBwoJoIhdXv71KZWugFqEphIS3PU60lEkFaz8RxaVsMpSvQxMBaKVwA5xg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
@endpush
```

**multi-step-form.blade**

```
<select wire:model="categories" name="categories[]" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true" required id="categories" title="{{ trans('select category') }}">
    @foreach($categories as $category)
        <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ (collect(old('categories'))->contains($category->id)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
            {{$category->category}}
        </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

## Some Failed Attempts

**Inside livewire component**

***Attempt 1***

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });
</script>
```

This works well but only once, i.e. at the start when livewire was loaded. This doesn't work, after the livewire component is updated by some input. So I added a code right below it:

***Attempt 2***

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
    });
</script>
```

This didn't work too. Some few articles had render separated in updated script so I did that too.

***Attempt 3***

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener('livewire:load', function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
    });

    document.addEventListener('livewire:updated', function () {
        $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
    });
</script>
```

Unfortunately this didn't work either.

I have tried adding the same scripts to my `app.js` too later, but am not sure where am I going wrong, and how can I make this working.

***Attempt 4***
Kept the scripts as is, and added wire:ignore in parent div

```
<div wire:ignore class="form-group">
    <select wire:model="categories" name="categories[]" class="selectpicker form-control" multiple data-live-search="true" required id="categories" title="{{ trans('select category') }}">
        @foreach($categories as $category)
            <option value="{{$category->id}}" {{ (collect(old('categories'))->contains($category->id)) ? 'selected' : '' }}>
                {{$category->category}}
            </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

As suggested in [livewire/livewire/issues/45](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/issues/45#issuecomment-513228288), but this didn't work as well.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't been that far off. Use Livewires Javascript lifecycle hooks documented [here](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/lifecycle-hooks).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
        Livewire.hook('component.initialized', (component) => {
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker();
            $('.selectpicker').selectpicker('render');
        })
    });
```